Drive between two cities, dynamic programming
A car goes from city A to city B. Both route A and B have n sections. A[1...n] and B[1...n] keeps the traffic information about sections of route A and route B respectively in terms of minutes. The cost of changing routes is k minutes, A->B and B->A possible. Should I define two dynamic programming recursion for route A and route B referencing each other? Then, the dp recurrences become circular, right?


(Using A to designate a city, a route, and an array of route information makes context all important to figure out which is meant in any one occurrence.) What exactly does changing routes mean: A[i] to B[i] (or vice versa)?

You can avoid circularity by adding an extra state to force a movement. The idea is that if you just moved from $A$ to $B$, it would be unwise to move back to $A$, otherwise you just wasted $2k$ minutes for nothing!
With that in mind, let $MinA[i][b]$ be the min cost to go from $A[i]$ to the goal, such that you MUST move forward in $A$ if $b=1$, and you don't need to if $b=0$. Similarly, define $MinB[i][b]$ but from $B[i]$. If you are at $MinA[i][0]$, you either go to $MinA[i+1][0]$, or $MinB[i][\color{red}{1}]$. If you are at $MinA[i][1]$, you MUST go to $MinA[i+1][0]$.
Can you take it from here?

upper_path[i] = min((upper_path[i-1]+A[i-1]), lower_path[i-1] + B[i-1] + k))
lower_path[i] = min((lower_path[i-1]+B[i-1]), (upper_path[i-1]+k))
Your approach is completely different than mine. I'll be glad if you define recurrence relations fully. I came up with this in order to prevent circularity in recurrence relation, do you think it is gonna work?
